# One command to tell if it is windows, osx or linux/unix

Tags: linux, windows, macos, cross-platform

Is there a way to determine the underlying OS platform just by running one command, irrespective of whether it is run on a command prompt in windows or a terminal (bash/sh/etc.) in OSX/Linux/Unix ?

Note: there may not be Python/Perl etc. or any such interpreters already present on the platform, so we can run any of these to figure out the same.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is "No", one command is not enough (at least not the same command). That's because environments are too different. You still can do this for OS X/Linux because they share same origin - Unix and thus `uname -a` would work. However Windows doesn't have this concept because it's not Unix-based. In windows you need to run another command to check version: `winver`

If anything, you can check host OS type with the help of come cross-platform tools, for example, some simple java utility or either of these Python oneliners:

```
python -c "import platform; print platform.platform()"
```

Gives more details

```
python -c "import platform; print platform.system()"
```

Gives only OS type

Comment: This is quite obvious. I was looking out for something more insightful.

Comment: If you do have Python you can run this oneliner:  `python -c "import platform; print platform.platform()"`  or  `python -c "import platform; print platform.system()"`